# PCI-e Serial Adapter RS-232/422/485 drivers

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, pci-express, serial

Excellent 2019 to each of you !

I bought the [PEX4S232485](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E2TZNH0) from StarTech couple of months ago to only have it mounted into a Debian Server (Stretch) today.

I confess I jump on that board without giving it much though as it was meant to be supported by "Linux 2.6.x kernels". 
The dumb question now: does it imply being supported by 4.4.x kernels too ? 
My dumb answer: I can't see why not (even if the Linux Kernel regression debate is tempting...)

The doubts are coming from these readings:

```
# ls /dev/ttyS*
    ttyS0  ttyS1  ttyS2  ttyS3
```

(/dev/ttyS0 being the MB serial port, working fine)

And then:

```
# cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A port:000003F8 irq:4 tx:363 rx:4 RTS|DTR
1: uart:unknown port:000002F8 irq:3
2: uart:unknown port:000003E8 irq:4
3: uart:unknown port:000002E8 irq:3
```

But also:

```
# lspci | grep -ni serial
55:0e:00.0 Serial controller: Systembase Co Ltd Device 4d02 (rev b0)
56:0e:01.0 Serial controller: Systembase Co Ltd Device 4d02 (rev b0)
61:13:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
62:14:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
```

Now I read a bit everywhere about the [magic command](https://placona.co.uk/getting-serial-ports-to-work-on-linux/):

```
# sudo setserial /dev/ttyS1 uart 16550A
```

But, huh, who wants to try this without really understand what it/(s)he does ?

So, any hints how I could double check that the board is detected, driver loaded ? Should I see the 'RTS|DTR' flag/voltage applied when plugged ?
(Now the thing is also the 4 DB9 connectors from the large 'octopus' board plug connector would make me expect ttyS[1-4] to be visible from CLI, but it stops at /dev/ttyS3.

Well, any hints/comments/suggestions are welcome.
I hope we are not back in the days when men were men and wrote their own device drivers ? ;0)

Comment: Oh well, yeah, the 'issue' being none of the chars issued on these ports through minicom are exciting the plugged scope (that shows pretty well the chars from the MB /dev/ttyS0..)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you only have the driver for the motherboard serial ports running, where only one of the 4 standard I/O address ranges is in use. So you need drivers for your PCIe serial adapter. First step is `lspci -nn` and google for vendor and device id you get (in the format `1234:1234`). Looking through the kernel sources will also help. Identifying the chip on the card by looking at it will also help.

Comment: Ha thx! Yes same deduction here as I remove the board and still see the same 4 I/O address range...I didn't know the '-nn' flag: will try ! Yes, I got the chipset: SystemBase - SB16C1052PCI and I do have the drivers installed on a Windows 10 machine, although not sure how 'easy' could a 'porting' activity be. Maybe buying another (Linux compatible) RS-422 board would be 'cheaper'..

Comment: Googling finds that SB16C1052PCI contains two 16C1055 UART. I couldn't find a data sheet for this specific UART, but if it's register-compatible with a 16550 UART, making a kernel driver should be trivial (use existing 16550 kernel driver, map to this card's PCI I/O BARs).

Answer (score 2):

Over a year late but I ran into the same issue and managed to get my adapter working. Turns out that Systembase has the Linux drivers available on their site. https://www.sysbas.com/en/downloads/pcie-serial-card-series/. I followed the readme and it worked.